# Shrimp/PhantomJS page size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, phantomjs, rack, shrimp

I've got a Rails 4 Shrimp solution that is putting out PDFs successfully via middleware. The only problem I have is that I need to control the size of the PDF page so that it can change each time. Is that possible, or what do I need to do differently? Ideally, I'd like to specify a page size in pixels each time, but any page size specification would help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [doc for the initialize method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/adeven/shrimp/Shrimp/Phantom#initialize-instance_method).

I did it this way:

```
# ruby

def create
  Shrimp::Phantom.new(html_file, options).to_file(pdf_file_location)
end

private

def options
  { format: "#{width}*#{height}" } # eg: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"
end
```